# Nested PL/SQL cursors and For loop work OK but "Connecting to the database xxx"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Intro:

I'm a PL/SQL beginner of 11g express. Hence guys, please show mercy.. This procedure has two nested cursors with one for loop, hoping to duplicate order rows based on the number of its occurrence number for further processing.

e.g. If order number > 2, duplicate the whole row and divide the transaction amount by its number for transaction amount.

Raw data:
Table:D_MP

```
BARCODE   Product    Amount         ID      Num
76Q7Q7    Water      10.00       20160601    2
8JJ1NK    Apple       5.50       20160601    1
8JJ1YK    Orange      4.50       20160608    1
8JJ1CK    Banana      4.00       20160608    2
```

Result:
Table:D_MP_1

```
  BARCODE   Product    Amount         ID      Num
    76Q7Q7    Water       5.00       20160601    1
    76Q7Q7    Water       5.00       20160601    1
    8JJ1NK    Apple       5.50       20160601    1
    8JJ1YK    Orange      4.50       20160608    1
    8JJ1CK    Banana      2.00       20160608    1
    8JJ1CK    Banana      2.00       20160608    1
```

Problem:

The output of this procedure looks all right, but every time I run it, the log of SQL Developer keeps goes "Connecting to the database xxx", not showing disconnected to database xxx, and I have to stop the procedure myself. Since I just have 10+ row of raw data for testing purpose, I wonder what prevents it from disconnecting/stopping.

---

Here's the code

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE MULTIPLE_CURSORS_TEST is
   pac_row D_MP%ROWTYPE;
   v_barcode D_MP.BARCODE%TYPE;
   v_Num D_MP.Num%TYPE;
   v_Amount D_MP.Amount%TYPE;
CURSOR mul_pa_LOOP_CURSOR
  IS
  Select *
  from D_MP;

CURSOR mul_pa_ID_CURSOR
  IS
  Select distinct ID
  from D_MP;

BEGIN 
  OPEN mul_pa_loop_CURSOR;
    LOOP
      OPEN mul_pa_ID_CURSOR;
       LOOP
          FETCH mul_pa_loop_cursor INTO pac_row;
            exit when mul_pa_loop_cursor%notfound;
            exit when mul_pa_ID_cursor%notfound;
            v_Num:= pac_row.Num;
            v_Amount:=pac_row.Amount/pac_row.Num;
        FOR i IN 1..v_Num
          LOOP
            INSERT INTO D_MP_1 ("BARCODE","Product", "Amount","ID","Num") 
            VALUES (pac_row."BARCODE",pac_row."Product",v_Amount,pac_row."ID",'1');
          END LOOP;
        COMMIT;
       END LOOP;
      CLOSE mul_pa_ID_CURSOR;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE mul_pa_loop_CURSOR;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS 
   THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END MULTIPLE_CURSORS_TEST;
```

Actually one cursor is sufficient enough just for this duplicating function. But I wanted to do more on each transaction level for promotional activities based on this procedure, so I stick to these two cursors, `mul_pa_LOOP_CURSOR` for entire rows and the other `mul_pa_ID_CURSOR` for each different transaction ID.

Feel free to comment on this procedure.

Comment: The exception handler is just mangling the error stack. The default behaviour with no exception handler is to display the error stack with line numbers and fail, which seems to be all you want to do with yours. SQLERRM already contains SQLCODE anyway (it's just the number after 'ORA' etc) so concatenating them together and saying 'An error was encountered' doesn't really improve anything. I'd get rid of the whole thing.

Comment: You rarely need to explicitly `open`, `fetch`, `exit when`, `close` etc. You can use the simpler syntax `for r in (select x from y where z) loop ... end loop;` which will save you a ton of code and might even be faster.

Comment: Thanks William! These are golden comments, very insightful on the simpler syntax thing. But the Scriptruner task keeps running for seconds even though I replaced the original exception handler with null. Guess I will spend more time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that `num` is always integer, it can be done using single SQL query:

```
select barcode, product, amount/num as amount, 1 as num
from table1 t1
join (
  select level l from dual
  connect by level <= ( select max(num) from table1 )
) x
on x.l <= t1.num 
order by 1,2

BARCOD PRODUC     AMOUNT        NUM
------ ------ ---------- ----------
76Q7Q7 Water           5          1
76Q7Q7 Water           5          1
8JJ1CK Banana          2          1
8JJ1CK Banana          2          1
8JJ1NK Apple         5,5          1
8JJ1YK Orange        4,5          1
```

On Oracle 12c it is even easier with a help of LATERAL JOIN:

```
select barcode, product, amount/num as amount, 1 as num
from table1 t1,
lateral (
  SELECT null FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t1.num
) x
order by 1,2
;

BARCOD PRODUC     AMOUNT        NUM
------ ------ ---------- ----------
76Q7Q7 Water           5          1
76Q7Q7 Water           5          1
8JJ1CK Banana          2          1
8JJ1CK Banana          2          1
8JJ1NK Apple         5,5          1
8JJ1YK Orange        4,5          1
```

Comment: This is really an out-of-box solution. Thank you! One more question though, I am confused by your 'order by' cause order by 1 I can understand, but what does 'order by 2' mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have three loops.

- First loop is for "mul_pa_loop_CURSOR"
- Second loop is for "mul_pa_ID_CURSOR"
- Third loop is a a FOR loop on numbers

You are fetching the record from only first loop. Atleast as per the code you have shared your second loop seems redundant. Try to either remove the second loop or move the FETCH and first EXIT statement in the first loop since currently they are in second loop.

```
OPEN mul_pa_loop_CURSOR;
  LOOP
    OPEN mul_pa_ID_CURSOR;
      LOOP
        FETCH mul_pa_loop_cursor INTO pac_row;   -- move this in first loop
        exit when mul_pa_loop_cursor%notfound;   -- move this in first loop
        exit when mul_pa_ID_cursor%notfound;
```

Like this

```
OPEN mul_pa_loop_CURSOR;
  LOOP
    FETCH mul_pa_loop_cursor INTO pac_row;
    exit when mul_pa_loop_cursor%notfound;

    OPEN mul_pa_ID_CURSOR;
      LOOP
        -- There should be a separate FETCH statement for this loop
        exit when mul_pa_ID_cursor%notfound;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I wanted to build on more functions for each transaction group so I created two cursors for each different transaction group of rows and you are 100% right, for these purposes I mentioned, one cursor is enough if I use cursor.